# Enable mid-string quick search in GtkTreeView

Tags: c, gtk

In GtkTreeView, there is a built-in search feature:

[image]

However, by default it only matches from the beginning of the string. So "parent" would match but "arent 0" would not.

Is there a way to change that default behavior so that searching would match mid-string as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [`gtk_tree_view_set_search_equal_func()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-search-equal-func) to set the function which does the comparison. Then implement a function which does sub-string searching.

Answer (score 2):

This is the search function:

```
gboolean
mid_search_func (GtkTreeModel *model, gint column,
                const gchar *key, GtkTreeIter *iter,
                gpointer search_data)
{
    gchar *iter_string = NULL;
    gtk_tree_model_get (model, iter, column, &iter_string, -1);
    return ! g_strrstr (iter_string, key) != NULL;
}
```

And in your treeview:

```
gtk_tree_view_set_search_equal_func(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view),
(GtkTreeViewSearchEqualFunc) mid_search_func, 
gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view), NULL);
```

This g_strrstr is case sensitive, so use g_utf8_strdown to transform everything in lowercase and compare if you want this behavior.